# Unable to start resource manager in yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I am getting the following error while starting the yarn cluster even after formatting the namenode.

Please suggest how to fix this.

```
2015-02-11 06:18:09,694 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-02-11 06:18:09,995 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RM_CONFIGURATION_FILES
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.LocalConfigurationProvider.getConfigurationInputStream(LocalConfigurationProvider.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1039)
2015-02-11 06:18:10,001 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2015-02-11 06:18:10,001 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2015-02-11 06:18:10,001 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: could you post your yarn-site.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Your yarn class-path might contain corrupted jars. Try executing

`yarn version`

It should display "This command was run using {PATH_TO}/hadoop-common-{hadoop_version}.jar"

If it displayed a different jar other than the hadoop-common.jar, then you might have to remove it from the yarn class-path